# Unity - if block is executed even when condition is false

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
void Update () {
    //------------ CHECKING "IF RUNNING" FOR ALL ACTIONS FROM LOCAL PLAYER ---------------------- 
    if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().Running)
    {
        Debug.Log("I Am Running");
        // ---------- orbiting and sending it -------------
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        ClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (ClockwiseOrbitPressPermit)
            {
                ClockwiseOrbitPressPermit = false;
                if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(1, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(1, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(2, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(2, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(3, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(3, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 1, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                StartCoroutine(ReactiveOrbit(OrbitCoolDown));
            }
        });
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        CoClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (CoClockwiseOrbitPressPermit)
            {
                CoClockwiseOrbitPressPermit = false;
                if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(1, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(1, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(2, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(2, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we start our orbit that maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet. also we send it once again in the end of continousorbit with speed value of zero.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendOrbit(3, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed);
                    Orbit(3, MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Center.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 2, InitialOrbitSpeed, BaseDeceleratorAmount);
                }
                StartCoroutine(ReactiveOrbit(OrbitCoolDown));
            }

        });


        // ---------- Shooting and sending it ------ - - - - - - -

        ShootButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (ShootPressPermit)
            {
                ShootPressPermit = false;
                if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Shoot, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendProduceBullet(1);
                    Shoot(1);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Shoot, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendProduceBullet(2);
                    Shoot(2);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Shoot, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendProduceBullet(3);
                    Shoot(3);
                }
                StartCoroutine(ReactiveShooting(MatchManager.GetMMInstance().LocalShootCoolDown));
            }
        });

        // ------------------ switching target and send it ----------------

        SwitchTargetButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (SwitchTargetPressPermit)
            {
                SwitchTargetPressPermit = false;
                if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().NearCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Switch, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendSwitchTarget(1);
                    SwitchTarget(1);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().MidCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Switch, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendSwitchTarget(2);
                    SwitchTarget(2);
                }
                else if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().FarCabin.Local)
                {
                    // we send this before we Switch, maybe it compensate possibly delay of internet.
                    Network.GetNetInstance().SendSwitchTarget(3);
                    SwitchTarget(3);
                }
                StartCoroutine(ReactiveSwitchTarget(SwitchTargetCoolDown));
            }
        });

        //-----------------------  END OF ACTION SCOPE -----------------------------

        // ----------------- WAITING AND CHECKING SOME EVENT -----------------------
        // ** these events can happen only during running state

        WaitingForCrippling();

        // ---------------------- END OF WAIT AND CHECK ----------------------------
    }

    // --------------- SOME CONTINUOUS UPDATING METHODS ---------------------
    // these actions don't need to be in running block and don't depend on running state. can happen in any moments. 
    UpdateTargetPosition();
    Debug.Log(MatchManager.GetMMInstance().Running.ToString());
}
```

When the scene runs, for a few seconds the "Running" value is "false" then it will change to "true". It will stay like this until the player's health becomes 0 at which point it will change to "false" again (this is a multiplayer game with 3 players).

The if-block includes some code that runs when UI buttons pressed. For those few seconds in the beginning that "Running" is false, everything works fine (pressing buttons won't work).

When it changes to true, it works fine again (pressing buttons will follow correct actions). However, when a player's health reaches 0, and the "Running" variable changes to "false" I can still press buttons and the actions and events 
also still happen!

I don't know what the problem is. I put the `Debug.Log("I Am Running");` and `Debug.Log(MatchManager.GetMMInstance().Running.ToString());` in the code, as you see and watched the value of "Running" variable every frame.

I have seen it be "false" and pressing buttons still executes actions like orbiting and switching target!

Comment: if(MatchManager.GetMMInstance().Running==true){} check with this

Comment: Could you have a race condition where `Running` is `true` at the start of the method, but changes to `false` by the end?  Also does `GetMMInstance` just return a local field or does it create/mutate the return value first?

Comment: @Joji Thomas Eapen: Checked. but still the same.

Comment: @ juharr: i am very sorry. i think maybe i heard the "race condition" but i don't know what is it?( note that the Running changes in a "few" places: 1) it  goes "false" when a player's health reaches 0" (by the "WaitingForCrippling();" that you can see in bottom of my code. ( Running will not change to true through any thing in Update.(pretty sure) 2) it Changes to false in another scrip in the end of match. 3) it changes to "true" only one time at the Start() and no where else. Also about "GetMMInstance", it is a singleton and i use it in many places in my code and it worked well till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save all your buttons' actions (Events.UnityAction) and remove them if "Running" is false, i.e.:

```
void Update () {
//------------ CHECKING "IF RUNNING" FOR ALL ACTIONS FROM LOCAL PLAYER ---------------------- 
    if (MatchManager.GetMMInstance().Running)
    {
        //...your previous code
        //save references to Events.UnityActions
    } 
    else
    {
        ClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveListener(referenseToTheAction1);
        CoClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveListener(referenseToTheAction2);

        // etc.; remove all Events.UnityAction listeners from other buttons.
    }
}
```

Or you can call in `else` statement `SomeButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();` for every button without saving references to Events.UnityActions.

Comment: Hey Sergey, i think you don't really know how much .. BUT i love you so so much. i am struggling with this problem for couple of days. and often fall in sleeping right on desk in front of my laptop. and now you helped me to come back to work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Armamedia, glad to help.

Comment: @Armamedia, could you please mark the answer if it helped you, thanks.

Comment: i tried it, as soon as i realized that it is helpful, but this error : thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.  ?!

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the action happens when you press the button the moment you added a onClick listener for your button that button will always do what you specified in the listener.

If you want it to stop you should remove the listener when your value is false. You can remove them all by using [RemoveAllListeners.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEventBase.RemoveAllListeners.html)

The point of adding a click listener is that you only specify once what the button click is suppose to do and it will do the exact same thing for each button click.

---

I would suggest you add only once your onClick listener in the start function and when you need your button to stop working you can disable the button. That way you don't always set a new onClick listener every single frame.

To disable the button you can set the [`interactable` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) to false

```
ClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
```

Then you can always set it back to `true` when you need it to be interactable again

```
ClockwiseOrbitButton.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
```

Comment: Your explanation help me very much in my new project. I wish I could mark to answers. Your is more helpful in this project.

Comment: @Armamedia It's okay don't worry about it, I'm happy I could help you out.